# cpu power mode occasionally changing to performance

Tags: cpu

The CPU power mode is occasionally changing to performance which causes my laptop to overheat and shutdown :(

Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Install this,

[CPU frequency scaling indicator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-cpufreq/), and set to lowest or desire frequency.

[image]

Comment: I'm using that one and it's set to ondemand.

Comment: You may change to **Powersafe** or the lowest speed e.g. **0.80GHz**.